# Add two tableviews from two xib file to main xib view

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib, nib

How to add two tableview from two xib file with two table controller to main xib view ? is this possible? 
Thanks in advance ?

Comment: Perhaps better to show content of these 2 tables in one two-sectioned UITableView?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible just add them as subviews programmatically in your main viewcontroller

sample code: put this in your main view controller's viewdidload method

```
    UITableView *tableview1 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableview1.delegate = self;
    tableview1.dataSource = self;
    tableview1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.6];
    [self.view addSubview:tableview1];

    UITableView *tableview2 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320,200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableview2.delegate = self;
    tableview2.dataSource = self;
    tableview2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.6];
    [self.view addSubview:tableview2];
```

Comment: can you give me an example or any reference? I search very much but i don't see any useful. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: again thanks you very much, but where i can put my sub xib view and controller for each table view ??

Comment: this example is without xib...you don't have to create xibs for these views...its easier without xibs.......